# How do you directly upgrade ASP.NET MVC1 to MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, upgrade

I have an ASP.NET MVC1 project and want to upgrade it directly to MVC3. I assume that there are two paths:

1. Upgrade directly from 1 to 3
2. Upgrade to 2 and then do a second upgrade to 3

Which is the path most traveled?

Comment: how will you upgrade? create new project and manually copy your controllers and views over, or do you have a different process in mind?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to establish. What is the easiest route to do a version 1 to version 3 upgrade...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the [ASP.NET Project upgrade tool](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008) you can only do the second path right now as stated in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx):

> The tool does not support Visual Studio 2008 solutions, MVC 1 projects, or projects targeting .NET 3.5. If you have a MVC 1.0 project you can use the old version of this tool to convert it to MVC 2.

I'm assuming you could manually upgrade directly to MVC 3, but why go through the hassle when you can run two wizards to upgrade the project for you.